# Load data from API into mdbootstrap datatable (vue.js, axios)

Tags: vue.js, axios, mdbootstrap

I want to load data from my API into a mdbootstrap datatable.

How can I write a method, that calls the getPosts() API and writes the results into the rows[] array?

```
<template>
   <mdb-datatable
      :data="data"
      striped
      bordered      
      >
</template>
<script>
   import { mdbDatatable } from 'mdbvue'
   import api from '@/api'
   export default {
     name: 'TPanels',
     components: {
       mdbDatatable },
     data: function () {
       return {
         loading: false,
         posts: [],
         model: {},
         claims: '',
         data: {
           columns: [{
             label: 'ID',
             field: 'immo_id',
             sort: 'asc'
           },
           {
             label: 'Titel',
             field: 'title',
             sort: 'asc'
           },
           {
             label: 'Preis',
             field: 'price',
             sort: 'asc'
           }],
           rows: [{
      immo_id: XXX,
      title: YYY,
      price: ZZZ,
   }],
         }
       }
     },
     async created () {
       this.refreshPosts()
       this.setup()
     },
     methods: {
       async setup () {
         this.claims = await this.$auth.getUser()
       },
       async isAuthenticated () {
         this.authenticated = await this.$auth.isAuthenticated()
       },
       async refreshPosts () {
         this.loading = true
         this.posts = await api.getPosts()
     }
   }
</script>
```

In my template (vue.js) I can access the API for example with:

```
<tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <td>{{ post.immo_id }}</td>
  <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ post.url }}</td>
  <td>{{ post.user_id }}</td>
</tr>
```

so I know that the API is working.
How can I do that please?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by writing the method getTableData(). Important is to use push() on the array in order to have vue rendering the html newly.

```
},
async created () {
  this.refreshPosts()
  this.setup()
  await this.getTableData()
},

},
  getTableData () {
    return api.getPosts().then(response => {
      var index
      let temp = response
      console.log(temp)
      for (index = 0; index < temp.length; ++index) {
        this.data.rows.push({
          title: temp[index].title,
          immo_id: temp[index].immo_id,
          price: temp[index].price
        })
      }
    }
    )
  }
```